# How to pass username:password to basic auth external WMS in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

A governmental agency provides a WMS layer with basic authentication. I added and published it on my Geoserver and it worked, but I could not access the different styles, which is my main problem now. They suggested me to connect directly to their GetCapabilities URL without going via Geoserver.

How do I set the username and password for the authentication in a secure way when connecting directly to their URL? Is it even possible with http?

```
var wmsLayer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://maps-ver.lantmateriet.se/fastighet/wms/v1.1?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1', {
                layers: 'granser',
                styles: 'morkbakgrund',
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true
            }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: It turned out that I need to set up a reverse proxy to handle it. How to do that - don't know, but will have to try find out.